# RewriteRule I guess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to change the link using RewriteRule or something in .htaccess?

- `www/player/?user=testuser`

to

- `www/player/testuser`

To display it I'm using:

```
<?php 
    $user = $_GET['user'];
?>
<title>
<?php echo $user; ?>
</title>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access
 `www/player/?user=testuser`

using the clean url

`www/player/testuser` you can use the following rule in your root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^player/(.+)$ /player/?user=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^clan/(.+)$ /clan/?tag=$1 [L]
```

This will internally redirect

- www/player/testuser

to

- www/player/?user=testuser

Comment: Works but how can I do more than one this rule?

Comment: RewriteRule ^player/(.+)$ /player/?user=$1 [L] and RewriteRule ^clan/(.+)$ /clan/?tag=$1 [L] dont work tougheter error 500 on the second rule page

Comment: @JarekP you need to add condition to the rule to exclude dir/file, see the edited code